# Is there a list of all the different media that Subaru has posters of in these scenes in season 2?

Tags: re-zero

During the flashback of Re Zero season 2, it's shown that Subaru has posters of various japanese media. Who are the characters featured and what series do they belong to? (I don't know if they are from anime, manga, light novels, etc)

[image]

Comment: The one on the right looks like from [vol. 2 of 学戦都市アスタリスク (*Gakusen Toshi Asterisk*, *The Asterisk War*) light novel](https://asterisk.fandom.com/wiki/Asterisk_Light_Novel_Volume_2).